# Adding Tab on Window Load for Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to add a tab whenever a new Firefox window is loaded for my bootstrap extension. I use this code listing:

```
var WindowListener = {
    setupBrowserUI: function(window) {
        window.gBrowser.selectedTab=window.gBrowser.addTab("http://google.com");
    },
    tearDownBrowserUI: function(window) {
    },
    // nsIWindowMediatorListener functions
    onOpenWindow: function(xulWindow) {
        var domWindow = xulWindow.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                                 .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
        // Wait for it to finish loading
        domWindow.addEventListener("load", function listener() {
            domWindow.removeEventListener("load", listener, false);
            // If this is a browser window then setup its UI      
            if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype")=="navigator:browser") domWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab=domWindow.gBrowser.addTab("http://google.com");
        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function(xulWindow) {
    },
    onWindowTitleChange: function(xulWindow, newTitle) {
    }
};

let wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].
       getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
// Wait for any new browser windows to open
wm.addListener(WindowListener);
```

You can try it in Scratchpad.

onOpenWindow method have the code to open tab in new window but it executes before the window is loaded completely so adding tab in this state does not seem to work although MDN code says "Wait for it to finish loading".

Setting a timeout by setTimeout function does the job but it looks ugly.

```
domWindow.setTimeout(function(){domWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab=domWindow.gBrowser.addTab("http://google.com");},1000);
```

Is it possible to add tab for new Firefox windows after window completely is loaded without setTimeouts?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a `setTimeout(..., 0)` hack. That ought to be the most reliable option and is used throughout the Firefox code itself :p

```
if (domWindow.gBrowser) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    domWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab =
      domWindow.gBrowser.addTab("http://google.com");
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. setTimeout works OK for now. My extension needs to add tab when browser starts up, too. In this case, previous session windows have lots of tabs and windows are loading pretty late, e.g. 5 or 10 seconds. But is it safe to use setTimeout(..., 0) for the windows that have 50 tabs or so? I mean does race condition happen here?

Answer (score 0):

It's really weird. I can't explain it. But from the line:

if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype")=="navigator:browser") domWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab=domWindow.gBrowser.addTab("http://google.com");

remove the `domWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab =` so change it to:

```
if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype")=="navigator:browser")  { 
     domWindow.gBrowser.addTab("http://google.com");
}
```

this succesfully loads the url BUT it doesnt select the tab SO I tried and absolutely new idea why this stuff FAILED:

```
if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype")=="navigator:browser")  { 
     var tab = domWindow.gBrowser.addTab("http://google.com");
}
```

as soon as i put that `var tab =` in front it fails. If it didn't fail i was planning to put on next line: `domWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab = tab`

THEN this also fails:
`loadOneTab` has `inBackground` parameter, if set it to false it will focus the tab:

```
if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype")=="navigator:browser")  { 
     domWindow.gBrowser.loadOneTab("http://google.com", {inBackground:false});
}
```

Absolutely no idea but this fails to load url but it focuses the tab. If you set `inBackground` to `true` it loads the url and of course it wont focus the tab. Absolutely weird...

Posted so others can maybe find out where the problem is, maybe we need to report something on bugzilla.

Comment: Thanks for alternatives. I remember there were an observer or event listener that would fire when UI and tabs totally loaded for the recent window, but I can not find it in MDN.